# ng-show not showing anything

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show

The problem is that when I acces .com/#/login or whatever URL, it does not show any error, but neither shows the login.html file

This is what I have:

```
<div id="content" ng-show></div>
```

and

```
staffApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/admin',
            {
                templateUrl: '/partials/admin_panel.html',
                controller: 'AdminController',
                access: access.admin
            }
        )

        .when('/',
            {
                templateUrl: '/partials/login.html',
                controller:  'LoginController',
                access: access.anon
            }
        );

    // use the HTML5 History API
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

});

With the access codes, templateUrls and controllers properly done.

Answer (score 1):

ng-show needs a variable to be bound on (e.g. ng-show="showContent", and as long it is truthy (showContent = true;) then it will appear.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

Right now it is not showing because ng-show is bound to undefined, which is a false value.

Comment: I did what you said, but it's still not loading anything

Comment: did you initialize the variable in your controller?

Answer (score 0):

Try this first to make sure it shows up like you think it should.

```
<div id="content" ng-show="true"></div>
```

Once you have debugged anything not allowing a hard coded ngShow="true" to show, you can mess with a variable.

Now do this...

```
<div id="content" ng-show="showMe">

In your controller || directive (that has access to the ng-show scope) initialize the variable.

$scope.showMe = false; (this is if you do not want it shown during initial DOM load, true otherwise)

Now in your controller || directive

function iShowThings(param){
  if( conditionIsTrue ){
    $scope.showMe = true; (when you wish to show it)
  }else{
    $scope.showMe = false; (hide it again)
  }
}

or perhaps a click event?
<button ng-click="toggleHiddenThing(showMe)">Toggle Div</button>

Then, in your controller || directive

$scope.toggleHiddenThing = function(showMe){ $scope.showMe = !showMe; }
In this case you would still initialize the showMe variable, then it's current
state would be passed into the function and then flipped with each click event.
```